# issue linking column of table to another table using LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, left-join, backend

I am trying to write a service that implements a recycle bin feature on a web app.

I have this so far that takes in an id, deletes from one table in my database and adds to another where id's are the same.

```
const deleteLocationMedia = (payload) => {
  const queryOne = `INSERT INTO recycle_bin
  SELECT * FROM location_media WHERE id =${payload}
  LEFT JOIN media m ON recycle_bin.media=m.id
  `;

  const queryTwo = `DELETE FROM location_media WHERE id = ${payload}`;

  return _apiDb.doubleRawSql(queryOne, queryTwo);
};
```

I am trying to left join using the id, the media column of the new recycle_bin table to an existing table that contains all the media data but I am getting a syntax error when deleting an image.

Still a junior and it's my first time getting let loose on the backend so any help would be appreciated.

Media Table (1) and current location media table i'm deleting from (2):

[image: Media Table:]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort it simply by moving the LEFT JOIN line of the first query into the second query